# How do I display CitiBike parking stations on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Can Google Maps be set up to display CitiBike parking stations in New York?

Right now, I have to first map out the drive in Google Maps, then go to CitiBike website to see where to get/drop the bike.

Answer (score 3):

I realized the best thing to do is use a pretty awesome app called [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/cities). It's actually a maps app, but Citibike info is integrated very well, and much easier to use than the actual Citibike app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Just search for citibike in Google Maps :)
It even displays realtime availability of bikes and docks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really easy, especially after Google Maps Update, which is still not able to load KML layers.
But you can use this tool to search for the walking/citibiking directions: http://dangoldin.com/citibike-station-directions/